# Flutter project image path saving problem : This expression has a type of 'void' so its value can't be used

Tags: java, android, ios, flutter, hive

```
    final imagePaths = <String>[];
    for (int i = 0; i < _imageFiles!.length; i++) {
      final imageFile = _imageFiles![i];
      final directory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
      final imagePath = '${directory.path}/${const Uuid().v1()}.jpg';
      final savedFile = await imageFile.saveTo(imagePath);
      imagePaths.add(savedFile.path);
    }
```

error ; saved.File.path
This expression has a type of 'void' so its value can't be used.

Why is it showing error?
Can someone help me please?

Comment: Where are the imageFiles coming from? It looks like the saveTo method might return void.  So you wouldn't be able to assign the value that saveTo returns to the savedFile variable.